# Two DateTime Validate if it is within the range of two DateTime

Tags: c#

I'am struggling on how to make this on code. please help.
I use c#

Here's the data:

```
    DateTime date_from = Convert.ToDateTime("2018/08/22 12:20:00");
    DateTime date_to =  Convert.ToDateTime("2018/08/28 07:25:00");

    DateTime other_date_from =  Convert.ToDateTime("2018/08/24 00:20:00");
    DateTime other_date_to=  Convert.ToDateTime("2018/08/25 00:21:00");
```

Now, I'd like to check if the data from `date_from` and `date_to` is within the range of `other_date_from` and `other_date_to`.

For example.

This datetime

> "2018/08/22 12:20:00 to 2018/08/28 07:25:00" : August 22 12:20 PM to August 28 07:25 AM

is within the range of

> "2018/08/24 00:20:00 to 2018/08/25 00:21:00"  August 24 12:20 AM to August 25 12:21 AM

If its within the range, it returns true, if not return false.

Comment: What does your code look like so far? And does the date range you provide have to fully overlap the range to be considered "in range"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a DateTime range is within another 3 month DateTime range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688791/how-to-check-if-a-datetime-range-is-within-another-3-month-datetime-range)

Answer (score 0):

This simple condition will do the trick !

```
date_from <= other_date_to && date_to >= other_date_from
```

Answer (score 0):

It's bit of head scratcher sometimes...

```
            DateTime date_from = Convert.ToDateTime("2018/08/22 12:20:00");
            DateTime date_to = Convert.ToDateTime("2018/08/28 07:25:00");

            DateTime other_date_from = Convert.ToDateTime("2018/08/24 00:20:00");
            DateTime other_date_to = Convert.ToDateTime("2018/08/25 00:21:00");

            bool bInRange = ((other_date_from > date_from & other_date_from < date_to) &
                            (other_date_to > date_from & other_date_to < date_to));
```